# Do I have to put 20% down on a condo so that I don't have to live in it for 1 year before renting it out to tenants?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, new-york, landlord, cash-flow

I really want to purchase a condo and rent it out to tenants for some extra cash flow here in Queens, NY.

I contacted a mortgage loan officer and he told me that I HAVE to put 20% down if I decide not to live in it and rent it out to tenants.  If I put, say, 5% (or anything < 20%) down - then he said I have to live there for 1 year before renting out.  Is this true?  I've looked it up but I see that this rule applies to FHA loans, not a conventional loan which's what I want to take out.

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: "_Is this true?_" Since _that_ loan officer told you that you have to, then presumably you have to _for that loan company_. Are you asking if there's a city/state/country-wide rule that says the minimum is 20%? Have you spoken to another company's loan officer? (And, do you _know_ that the first officer knew you didn't want an FHA loan?)

Comment: I have the feeling you haven't really thought this through. How much *net* cash flow are you expecting after you use the rental income to pay the mortgage and any other associated condo fees and expenses?

Comment: @TripeHound He said I must put 20% down if I decide not to live in it and rent it out to tenants, which's my intentions.

Comment: @chepner I already know how much net cash flow I'm expecting even after paying mortgage and other condo fees.  I just want to know if it's true that I have to live in the condo for 1 year if I put less than 20% down.

Comment: @user99000 What I meant is... you ask "_Is this true?_" to which the answer must be  "_yes it is true (at least for that particular loan company), because that was what the loan officer said_". My comment was intended to see if you wanted to know whether this rule is one that _that particular company_ has **chosen** to enforce, or whether there is some city/state/country-wide law or regulation that **forces** them to impose this rule. In the first case, a _different_ lender may give a different answer; in the second case, all lenders will say the same.

Comment: @user99000 The fact that you appear to have spoken to *one* loan officer, and you need to ask *here* for advice as to what is normal, suggests that this is just one of *many* aspects of becoming a landlord that you have not thought out.

Comment: @chepner I'm obviously going to speak to more than one loan officer.  I just thought it'd be a good question to ask so I can have more intel when contacting the second loan officer.  Everyone has to start somewhere.

Comment: I think it's perfectly reasonable to ask "Is this a common thing?"  Welcome new user!

Answer (score 9):

This is how it works in my experience regarding getting a mortgage:

- Owner occupied. If you put less than 20% down you have to get PMI.
- Rental. You are required to put 20% down. Not all lenders will make loans for rental property.

Now some people start with a owner occupied and change to renting the property years later. They do this when they have to move for a job, or they outgrow the house. When that happens the lender doesn't require the owner to increase the equity by making a big payment. They also don't terminate the loan if they don't write loans for rental properties, they allow it to continue.

The loans I have had, required a statement that I would be occupying the home soon after settlement and planned to occupy it  for al least x months afterwards.

Check all the settlement documents, there should be a statement regarding required occupancy. You may have even signed it during the application process or during the approval process.

If that lender requires a year of occupancy then that is what they require. If you know you are never going to live in the place then you only option is get a loan for rental property, unless you want to lie or commit fraud.